# Angular 11 You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, service, undefined, angular-services

I'm not getting error message and error code when it comes from server side in angular.

below code I'm using for all service.

I'm using angular 11 and in the below code getting error

```
postEvidenceFiles(path: string, data: any, _arguments?: HttpParams) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set(
      'Authorization',
      `Bearer ${this.AuthStorageService.getToken()}`,
    );

    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json, text/plain,');

    const options = {
      headers,
    };

    return this.intercept(
      this.http
        .post<any>(path, data, options)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError)),
    );
  }
```

Intercept:

```
intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
    this.pendingRequests++;
    /*  NProgress.start(); */

    return observable.pipe(
      tap(
        () => {
          // Do nothing
        },
        (error) => {
          if (error?.status == 401) {
            // Redirect to login page
            // console.log(error)
            this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
              queryParams: { return_url: this.router.url },
            });
          }
        },
      ),
      finalize(() => {
        this.pendingRequests--;
        if (this.pendingRequests <= 0) {
          /*    NProgress.done(); */
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```

and handle error :

```
  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // console.log(error);
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      // console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
      return throwError(error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      // console.error(
      //    `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      //    `body was: ${error.error}`
      // );
      return throwError(error.error);
    }
  }
```

Please review and let me know where I'm getting wrong in this.

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use HttpInterceptor service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    //your logic
    httpRequest = httpRequest.clone({
      headers: httpRequest.headers.set("Bearer", 'TOKEN'),
    });

    return next.handle(httpRequest);
  }
}
```